# MegaRAID: what does "Is VD emulated: No" mean

Tags: raid, lsi, megaraid, megacli

When executing "MegaCLI -LdInfo -LdAll -a0", some of my servers report a property "Is VD emulated: No", and some report "Is VD emulated: Yes". I could not find an explanation for this setting, or how to change it.

The storcli program allows to "set emulationType=0|1|2" but it does not affect the mentioned flag.

The servers are different, some have SAS drives, other have SATA drives, also some are using original LSI cards, other use SuperMicro clones.

Can someone explain what this setting is, and whether it might affect the performance?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a matter of drive sector size emulation. That is, "isvdemulated" being 'yes' is a 512E drive, and 'no' is be a 512N drive.

Comment: Drive sector size emulation a 512E?  What can you possibly mean?

Comment: Modern hard drives use a sector size of 4 kilobytes. These are called 4kN drives. Some of these modern hard drives use a technology that allows them to look like drives with sector sizes of 512 bytes. These drives often have a designation of 512E or 512 emulated. "isvdemulated" refers to the presence or absence of this emulation technology (as I understand it). In case you are unclear on the topic of hard drive sector sizes, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_sector